# where to dispose StreamWriter if I need it during entire application lifetime?

Tags: c#

Where to dispose StreamWriter if I need it during entire application lifetime? I'm going to dispose it in destructor, will that work? I have to dispose to flush data, and I don't want to use `AutoFlush` feature because from msdn: `"You can get better performance by setting AutoFlush to false, assuming that you always call Close (or at least Flush) when you're done writing with a StreamWriter."`

So should i `Dispose` in destructor like in the code below?

```
class Log
{
    private static StreamWriter swLog = new StreamWriter("logMAIN.txt");

    static ~Log()
    {
        swLog.Dispose();
    }

    public static void Push(LogItemType type, string message)
    {
        swLog.WriteLine(type + " " + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay + " " + message);
    }
}
```

**upd** instead of `Dispose` i meant to call `Close` but it is not improtant in this case because they seems doing exactly the same.

Comment: Just use `File.WriteAllText` and don't bother with `StreamWriter`.

Comment: If you are doing it for logging consider using existing tracing frameworks (one that is part of .Net Framework, or one of may external ones like Log4Net) that already solved all issues you are hitting and will discover in future (like multi-thread access, log rotation, IO failures, extensibility...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be basing your decision not to flush on some performance information from MSDN. That's not where I'd start.

Do you have *evidence* that using AutoFlush causes you *significant* performance problems?

Have you considered alleviating these performance problems in a different way, e.g. having a single thread writing to the `StreamWriter`, either auto-flushing or periodically flushing every 20 seconds or whatever?

You haven't told us what kind of application you're writing, mind you - that can make a significant difference in terms of how much you know about shutdown.

Also note that the code you've given isn't thread-safe to start with. You could end up using the `StreamWriter` from multiple threads concurrently; I doubt that `StreamWriter` is particularly designed for that scenario.

Comment: I have many different logs in my applications, some of them, as this, is used from one thread only. Probably `AutoFlush` feature will be fine for me, but as I don't need logs immediately I was thinking not to use it. There are no reason for me to use `AutoFlush` and it turned off by default in .NET so I decided to use "default" scenario.

Comment: @javapowered: "There are no reason for me to use AutoFlush" - well, apart from the fact that you want to make sure you don't lose any logs even if your app is shut down? You *still* haven't explained what kind of app you're writing, and whether you have a well-defined exit point...

Comment: application is used for HFT trading. well yes I exit only when application shutdowns :) or what do you mean by `exit points`?

Comment: why can't I just implement so simple thing: "keep streamwriter open until outer class is disposed. flush everything on the disk when outer class is disposed".

Comment: @javapowered: You can. But you haven't told us what *kind* of app it is - web app, rich client etc. If you can tell the right time to dispose of your logs, then sure - dispose of them then.

Comment: it's just console application

Comment: @javapowered: Okay, finally, some information. And do you have multiple threads, or is it all just one thread? If you have multiple threads, are any of them background threads? If you *can* just dispose of everything cleanly as you exit, that will be the easiest approach... although it does mean that you'll probably find `IDisposable` sneaking all the way through your code, just for the sake of logging. I'd still urge you to at least *consider* simply auto-flushing...

Comment: some logs are multithreaded, i'm using `lock (this)` inside `Push` method in this case. I think I don't use background threads (but i'm using `Tasks`. thanks Jon I think i will just use `AutoFlush` until this becomes a problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem really is the way the `StreamWriter` is initialized. Using a regular object like this

```
using (var logger = new Log())
{
    app.Run();
}
```

The `StreamWriter` can still be a static field in the `Log` class, but is initialized and disposed at known points in time rather than using a static initializer.

For this to work you will need to let you log class implement the `IDisposable` interface and dispose the `StreamWriter` in the `Dispose` method like this:

```
class Log: IDisposable
{
    private static StreamWriter swLog;

    public Log()
    {
       swLog = new StreamWriter("logMAIN.txt");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        swLog.Dispose();
    }

    public static void Push(LogItemType type, string message)
    {
        swLog.WriteLine(type + " " + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay + " " + message);
    }
}
```

Also note how the `Log` will be disposed even if an exception is thrown.

Comment: You haven't explained *how* the StreamWriter would be "initialized and disposed at known points in time" - where disposal is the important point here.

Comment: and if I have several (or dozen) different logs I should write a lot of nested `using` blocks?

Comment: yeah, why not? Or create a new class that has a list of logs that gets disposed when *it* is disposed. One class, one responsibility.

Comment: @Jon true. that part is hopefully a bit more clear after the edit

Comment: @vidstige: Actually, it's worse now. Now if you've got two `using` blocks creating separate instances in different threads, you could dispose of the `StreamWriter` in one thread while you're trying to use it in another. Ouch. Obviously if your app is simple enough to have a well-controlled exit point, the question is trivial. I would imagine that's not the case, although the OP hasn't said what kind of app this is.

Comment: @Jon This is the problem in the original code too. Remember the finalizer runs in its own thread. The question of access from multiple threads does only vaguely relate relate to the question *when* to dispose the StreamWriter. My assumption is the opposite as you guessed, the application has a well defined exit point.

Comment: @vidstige: The original code won't even compile, as there's no such thing as a static finalizer. But suggesting a solution which mutates a static variable *on construction*  isn't a good answer, IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet my bad, let's just remove `static` from destructor and assume that this class is used from one thread only... hm however I need multithreaded version too

Comment: @javapowered: Now you're assuming that your finalizer will be executed before the finalizer for the underlying stream. There's no guarantee of that. Basically, you shouldn't use finalizers in this case.